# How to kill Camera.exe without going back to start menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an WPF application that calls camera by process.start() and then using filewatcher to monitor .jpg files on the picture\camera roll folder. If theres changes, it would close the camera.exe by process kill, but it would show start menu, i tried Window + D on that but it won't work, or SetForeGroundWindow. Can anybody help me?. I am testing on a windows 8.1 tablet.

Comment: Post some example code, specifically the process kill code which reproduces the start menu issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click taskbar -> `Properties` -> `Navigation` -> Check `When I sign in or close all apps, ...`. This should take you to desktop after you close the app.

The registry entry is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartPage`

**Option name**: When I sign in or close all apps on a screen, go to the desktop instead of Start

**DWORD**: `OpenAtLogon`

To enable option, set `DWORD` value to 0 and to disable this option, set `DWORD` value to 1

Comment: This solved it, i just need to set it on the registry, wonder if you know the path.

Comment: found the entry here.. http://www.askvg.com/registry-tweaks-to-customize-taskbar-navigation-and-start-screen-settings-in-windows-8-1/

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to reply on this answer, sorry.

Comment: Almost 4 years! Phew, time flies fast :)